# How to translate a matrix in using Eigen

Tags: eigen

I have a 3*3 matrix, and want to translate each column.

```
#include <Eigen/geometry>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
  Translation3d tr(1,2,3);
  Matrix3d m; m<<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
  // m = tr * m; //will not work
}
```

Don't have a clue from the Eigen manual...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual says `Translation` is not to be used directly.

For transforms, you will likely want `Affine3d`, but note that your matrix `m` is not a homogeneus matrix, so you either change it to be `4x4` or use another `Affine3d` object.